# How to fork and npm install in my project

Tags: github, npm, package

I have a [package](https://github.com/articodeltd/angular-cesium)

I would like to fork it, edit some stuff in order to make it fit into my project, but keep the ability to update from the original master.

I forked the project, and now I am stuck because when I npm install it, I have "unknown module angular-cesium"

the `package.json` scripts is has follow :

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "demo:start": "ng serve",
    "demo:build": "ng build --prod",
    "demo:server": "nodemon --exec ts-node --project demo-server/tsconfig.json -- demo-server/src/main.ts",
    "lib:build": "ng build angular-cesium; npm run copy:extra-files",
    "lib:start": "ng build angular-cesium --watch",
    "lib:publish": "npm run lib:build; cd dist/angular-cesium; npm publish; cd ...; npm run docs:push",
    "test": "ng test angular-cesium",
    "test:ci": "ng test angular-cesium --no-watch --browsers=ChromeHeadless",
    "lint": "ng lint angular-cesium",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "gh-pages": "gh-pages -d docs -b gh-pages",
    "copy:extra-files": "cp README.md LICENSE.txt dist/angular-cesium",
    "docs:run": "compodoc -p projects/angular-cesium/src/lib/tsconfig.compodoc.json --theme stripe -d docs -n \"Angular Cesium\" --watch --serve",
    "docs:compile": "rimraf docs && compodoc -p projects/angular-cesium/src/lib/tsconfig.compodoc.json --theme stripe -d docs -n \"Angular Cesium\"",
    "docs:push": "npm run docs:compile && npm run gh-pages && rimraf docs",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run lib:build; npm run demo:build"
  },
```

I tried to add `"prepare:npm run lib:build"`

I have the follow error :

```
 Project 'angular-cesium;' does not support the 'build' target.
```

if I just try a npm publish I get the following

```
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Popolee\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-33912-632e340c\tmp\fromDir-ffb525d2\package.tgz'
```

My question is, how can I fork this library, and make a npm installable custom version that I can edit and install in my project when i want